# "Client Error: Settings Conflict" when trying to add allowed domain to spam filter policy

Tags: email, office365

I'm getting the above message when attempting to add one of our trading partners' domain to the **Allowed Domains** list for the **Anti-Spam inbound policy** in the **[Office 365 Security & Compliance](https://protection.office.com/antispam)** portal. I'm able to get to the **Manage allowed domain** window and click the "**+**". I then enter, e.g., `newalloweddomain.com`, hit **`[ENTER]`** (or click the "tooltip" box) to have it show up below the textbox, and click the **Add domains** button at the bottom.

[image: Adding allowed domain]

Then I click **Done**. I'm able to complete all of these steps without error but, when I click the final **Save** button on the main **Allowed and blocked senders and domains** screen, I get the error mentioned above (and displayed in this screenshot):

[image: Client Error: Settings conflict!]

I've tried with a few different domains - both real and bogus - all resulting in the same error. I've tried adding a "dummy" specific address to the **Allowed Senders** list and get the same thing. I've also checked to confirm that the domain name I'm trying to add is not already in the allowed list. I've even gone through the other allowed *and* blocked lists to ensure that neither the domain nor any specific address using that domain is listed in any of them. I've added domains and individual addresses to these lists in the past without issue using this portal (although they've obviously "updated" it since the last time I was in there), so I'm not sure where else to look for potential settings conflicts. What other Office 365 administration settings might be causing this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AdamV - you need to open Exchange admin center in the classic view, and not the updated version.  Choose Protection then Spam Filter and it will allow you to add to the allow/block list

Comment: Well, that seems to have worked. I'd still like to know what's causing the error, but at least I can add things to those lists now.

Answer (score 1):

Good Day All - I was having the same issue and what I had found in reviewing the email I was trying to add to the 'Safe' List, was already in the 'Blocked' List, thus the conflict.

I tested the theory by removing the email from the blocked list and the safe list where I had added them in the Classic Exchange Admin Center, proceeded to add the same email to the safe list in the 'New' Security area and this worked, no conflict.

Comment: Thank you for that, but that doesn't appear to be the issue in my case. I checked all of the other lists, including the allow/block individual sender lists as well as the allow/block domain lists and the domain I'm trying to add doesn't exist in any of them.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same error. After cancelling my way out, going back in and clicking Save without making any changes, I still got the error. In other words, if it's the first time you've tried to edit the block/allow lists since the recent portal update, the error probably has nothing to do with the entry that you are trying to add - it's the conflict check that's new, and it's found a conflict that was already there (or maybe multiple conflicts).

Using the classic EAC worked for me, which is all very well until they remove that option, and we're left with policies that we can't edit until we find and remove the conflicts.

This is one of those all-too-frequent cases where I wonder if the programmers were deliberately being as unhelpful as possible, or whether they are just lazy. If the program can identify the fact that there is a conflict, then you'd think it would be easy to get it to tell you exactly which entries are conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you end up finding a resolve for this error, oddly enough I am seeing the same issue however with adding users to the block list.  This happens on both blocking for senders and domains.

Comment: As of yet, I've not found a solution. It isn't a high enough priority on my task list to focus my energies on finding a solution at this time, so I'm just hoping that some kind SysAdmin somewhere will post something helpful.

Comment: Well if I happen to find something I will let you know ;)

Answer (score 0):

i got the same error this morning, I was able to edit the policy via the ECP (the old way) rather than using the protection.office.com.

Comment: Can you be more explicit and describe the steps to do this, or at the very least point to an article which explains them?

Answer (score 0):

I've been managing our anti-spam list in the 0365 portal for months in the new format.  This morning I log in, it looks a little different, and its giving me the "Client Error Settings Conflict" message.  I'm doing it the same way I always do, why the issue now?  For the question above, to get there do the following:

1. Login to O365 Portal
2. Click "Exchange" to open the Exchange Admin portal
3. Go to the bottom and click "Classic Exchange Admin Center"
4. From the Dashboard under "Protection" click "Spam Filter"

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the allowed senders/domains and the blocked senders/domains to make sure that if you are allowing a sender/domain that you are also not blocking the same sender/domain worked to fix this is in our domain.  Thank you for posting.